# Azure B2C: User Flow suddenly disappeared

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My Azure Active Directory B2C User Flow policy **B2C_1_SignUpAndSignIn** suddenly disappeared in Portal UI even though it still exists. It seems to be somehow "hidden" from the UI.
[image]

I can proof that the policy still exists but just not displayed because users are still able to sign in and if I want to recreate the same policy with same name I get the following message:

[image]

Filters are not set!

It happened around the same time where I deleted a custom user attribute. Maybe it is an Azure Portal Bug (which would be rather critical)? Has someone else experienced something similar?

Comment: Sticking together the direct link to the user flow blade manually works

Answer (score 1):

After about an hour it magically reappeared without me doing anything. Must have been an Azure Portal oddity.